# Disadvantage of interstage trusses on Soyuz launch vehicle?

Tags: saturn-v, aerodynamics, soyuz-launcher, efficiency

Brian Tompsett gave a detailed explanation of the advantages of the trussing in his answer to the question [Why do the Russians use these fence-like interstage fairings?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19374/why-do-the-russians-use-these-fence-like-interstage-fairings)

The gap between Stage II and Stage III [in this depiction](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/soyuz-fg.html) depicts the interstage trussing.

[image]

Other than the inefficiency in streamlining and drag, are there other disadvantages to the trussing compared to the interstage fairing of the Saturn V? (Fairing-the hollow metal cylinder surrounding nozzles at the bottom of the second stage in the following [depiction](http://heroicrelics.org/info/saturn-v/saturn-v-general.html))

[image]

Comment: I think you answered it yourself: "inefficiency in streamlining and drag"

Comment: @OrganicMarble So there are no other disadvantages?

Answer (score 1):

'Hot staging' like it is done on Sojus rockets requires the top side of the lower stage to be isolated using a small heat shield, that may slightly reduce payload.

Also, when hot-staging, separation has to be well-timed - too late, and the upper stage cannot ignite as the engines of the lower stage have stopped burning, too early, and the rocket may lose a significant amount of DeltaV.

[image]