# How do current reusable boosters create fuel pressure for retro-burn?

Tags: liquid-fuel, booster-flyback, fuel-system

For the SpaceX launches of the Falcon9 and Falcon Heavy, and also Blue Origin launch vehicles, the booster stage lands with a controlled decent and firing of main engines for retro-thrust.

During lift-off and rocket burn, inertial 'forces' keep the propellant at the valve end of the tank, but once this thrust stops, the tank is in free-fall. Gas thrusters then reorient the unit for retro-burn to de-orbit.

During this process, how are the propellant and LOX directed to the valves that direct the components to the engine nozzle?

Comment: Nice to see so wonderful first posts here (from Review).

Comment: Also related: [Starting a liquid fuel engine in zero gravity](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2446/starting-a-liquid-fuel-engine-in-zero-gravity).