# Why do upper stages spin before deploying satellites?

Tags: artificial-satellite, orbital-maneuver, attitude, upper-stage

I saw the [Ariane 6 animation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QAKvIugfzY), and I noticed, that the upper stage spins before deploying the satellites. Why are they doing this? Is it necessary or is it possible to successfully deploy a satellite to orbit without spinning it? Are the satellites spinning throughout their mission or they will stop spinning after reaching their desired orbit?

Comment: See also [How is spin stability used in spacecraft?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/867/49), [Why does NASA intentionally spin space probes?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/2383/49), and a few other questions tagged as [tag:attitude].

Answer (score 7):

It's a stabilization technique.  I'm not sure what you mean by "is it necessary"...they don't do things "just because" in rocketry.  It's an alternative to three-axis stabilization.

The satellites are usually despun after the burn(s), often by the amusingly named "[yo-yo de-spin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_de-spin)".  (good animation at link)

Comment: By "is it necessary" I mean is it possible to successfully deploy a satellite to orbit without spinning it.

Comment: Sure, they could use a three-axis stabilization system.  Like all things aerospace, it's a tradeoff between cost, weight, schedule, and performance for the particular application.  Back in the days when Shuttle deployed comsats, PAMs were spun, and IUSs used three axis stabilization.